# Informatica - Using single target multiple times in single mapping

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

Can you use a target table in multiple areas of a single mapping.

I have routers around the table, where I know some rows are ready, and currently they are all going to a final Union transformation.

I am wondering if it is possible to direct these from the router, directly into the multiple instance of a single target table.

If so, how does Informatica do the inserts?

Will it each time queue the outputs into the same target, or try and insert them concurrently when and as it stumbles upon them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of course. We use multiple target instances (of same target) all the time. Informatica processes one row at a time, unless you have configured partitioning on the session. So, only one record gets inserted at a time.

Even if your router produces rows in multiple output groups, for a single input row (happens when the group conditions are overlapping or not mutually exclusive), then also, informatica will process the output groups sequentially. This is because, for un-partitioned sessions only one writer thread writes to all target instances. So all rows are processed sequentially by that writer thread.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use multiple instances of target in informatica, the load process will depend on the way you design the mapping.

There are two ways of loading target they are:

1. target load order;
2. constraint base load.